# memory crash in iOS 6

Tags: ios7, memory-management, ios6, automatic-ref-counting, xcode-instruments

If i open my video record app for an half hour automatically crashes happen in `ios6` for both `ipad` and `iPhone`. when i see `debug navigator` window it shows automatically increase `memory size` by `+1` for every second , is there any solution to solve this.

Comment: check this Apple's Doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: and also check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: @MohitPopat these are for `NON-ARC` but what about `ARC`.

Comment: for `ARC` http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/understand-memory-management-under-arc/

Answer (score 2):

Using `retain` and `release` to manage our memory uses a model called reference counting. Each object has a `retain count` and this is used to keep track of ownership.

Once an object’s retain count is reduced to zero, it is deallocated.

- `alloc` - allocates memory for new object with retain count of 1.
- `retain` - increments retain count of object by 1.
- `release` - decrements retain count by 1.
- `autorelease` - decrements retain count by 1 at the end of the current [autorelease pool block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).
- `copy` - creates copy of object with retain count of 1.

P.S.: I'd suggest using [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html).